# Django + Ajax срабатывает событие error, вместо success

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

Попытался реализовать Ajax запрос при нажатии на кнопку удаления статьи. При использовании запроса POST, как показано ниже, всегда срабатывало событие error, вместо success.

handler.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function delArticle(event) {
        $.ajax ({
            url: window.location.pathname + 'delete/',
            method: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert("Before Send!")
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("SUC! " + data.msg);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("ERR! " + data.error_msg);
            }
        });
    }

    $("#btn-deletearticle").bind("click", delArticle)
});
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from . import ajax_handler

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '',
        views.index,
        name='index'
    ),
    path(
        'Wcs4q9rXQKsPzVYf63Ome1VM',
        admin.site.urls
    ),
    path(
        'contacts/',
        views.contacts,
        name='contacts'
    ),
    path(
        'news/<int:pk>/',
        views.article,
        name='article'
    ),
    path(
        'news/<int:pk>/delete/',
        ajax_handler.deletearticle,
        name='deletearticle'
    ),
    path(
        'forms/',
        include('html_forms.urls')
    ),
    path(
        'accounts/',
        include('django.contrib.auth.urls')
    ),
]
```

ajax_handler.py:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from Main.models import Articles


def deletearticle(request, pk):
    # if request.user.is_authenticated()\
    #         and request.is_ajax()\
    #         and request.POST\
    #         and request.uesr.has_perm("Main.delete_articles"):
    #     item = Articles.objects.filter(id=pk).update(status="deleted")
    return JsonResponse({"msg": "Some message..."})
```

Затем я попытался сделать тоже самое с GET запросом, и событие success начало срабатывать. Но когда я раскомментировал код для изменения данных в БД, снова стало происходить событие error.

ajax_handler.py:

```py
def deletearticle(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated()\
            and request.is_ajax()\
            and request.GET\
            and request.uesr.has_perm("Main.delete_articles"):
        item = Articles.objects.filter(id=pk).update(status="deleted")
        response = "GOOD NEWS!"
    else:
        response = "BAD NEWS!"
    return JsonResponse({"msg": response})
```

В файле handler.js, разумеется, метод был также изменён на GET.
Когда срабатывает событие error, сообщение выглядит так: "ERR! undefined", как будто не срабатывает ни if ни else. И даже если уже после блоков if-else вставить отдельно `response = "Some Foken msg"`, результат остаётся тот же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что для POST запросов применяется CSRF защита

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf.

У вас 2 варианта:

1. отключить проверку токена декоратором (csrf_excempt)
2. отправлять токен (пример https://github.com/alexsok-bit/one_time_notes/blob/master/source/design/static/dropnote/show.js#L10)

Comment: Действительно, это помогло, спасибо. Кроме того, нужно было убрать круглые скобки при проверке параметров request.user.is_authenticated и request.is_ajax. Правда запрос ещё отказывался работать с request.uesr.has_perm("Main.delete_articles"), выдавая ошибку `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'uesr'`, и как это исправить не имею ни малейшего понятия. Не подскажете, что с этим делать?

Comment: request.uesr. - опечатка же. request.user

Comment: Боже, мне точно следует отдохнуть. Уже не вижу ни черта в своём же коде. Спасибо)